# Using Flutter Hooks library, I'm getting a race conflict when I try to use the navigator in useEffect

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

Flutter Hooks [useEffect Docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_hooks/latest/flutter_hooks/useEffect.html)

I dispatch an API request in my onSubmit event that has a side effect of turning `signupHelper.state.success` to true.  I would like to navigate to another screen when success == true.  Instead I get an error for `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build`

My current workaround is to wait 50 milliseconds before navigation to make sure there is no rebuild going on.

My code looks like this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import '../hooks/use_signup_helper.dart'


class SignupForm extends HookWidget {
  const SignupForm({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this wraps useReducer and gives me access to state and dispatch
    final signupHelper = useSignupHelper();  

    useEffect(() {
     
      if (signupHelper.state.success) {
        
        // this is my workaround - delay 50 milliseconds to avoid rebuild conflict
        // Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50))
        //    .then((_) => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home'));
    
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home'));
      }
      return null;
    }, [signupHelper.state.success]);

    return ... // UI goes here
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same issues and I came across wrap the `Navigator.push` with `Future.microtask`

```dart
    useEffect(() {
      if (condition) {
        Future.microtask(() async {
          PageResult result = await Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NextPage(),
            ),
          );
          if (result == null) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          } else {
            // ...
          }
        });
      }
      return;
    }, [value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we can use the ScheduleBinding and SchedulerPhase class.  It is imported like this -

```dart
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
```

And the new useEffect function looks like this -

```dart
    useEffect(() {
      if (signupHelper.state.success) {
        if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase != SchedulerPhase.idle)
          SchedulerBinding.instance.endOfFrame.then((_) {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
          });
        else
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
      return null;
    }, [signupHelper.state.success]);
```